# Improper Integrals Comparison Method

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have the Integral:
$$\int^\infty_{20}\frac{1}{x\cdot \ln^{15}(x)}\,dx$$
I know that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\ln(x)) = \infty$$

Subsequently, I could substitute with $$\ln(x)$$ in the denominator and try to prove that this integral is convergent because $$f(x) > g(x)$$
But it does not seem to be working. Because it seems divergent and could not state the same for a smaller function. Could you suggest another substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The integral
$$
\int_{20}^\infty\frac{dx}{x(\ln(x))^{15}}
$$
can be rewritten as 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{20}^t\frac{dx}{x(\ln(x))^{15}}.
$$
Then, use the substitution $u=\ln(x)$ to get that this integral is 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\ln(20)}^{\ln(t)}\frac{du}{u^{15}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, it seems easy. The problem was that I did not know that I am able to do the transition between the second and the third step, so I tried another way.